# Simple aggregate in R

Tags: r

I try to do simple aggregate in R by this code:

```
test <- data.frame(a=c("x","y","x","y"), 
                  b=c(2,3,4,5))
test2 <-aggregate(test, by=list(test$a),FUN="sum", na.rm=TRUE)
```

Dataset test looks like this:

```
  a b
1 x 2
2 y 3
3 x 4
4 y 5
```

And I want the answer test2 to be:

```
  a b
1 x 6
2 y 8
```

I get an error message:

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L), na.rm = TRUE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: I would go with `aggregate(b ~ a, test, sum, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Need to specify the column to sum by: `aggregate(test$b, by=list(test$a), FUN="sum", na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
test2 <- aggregate(data=test,b~.,FUN = sum)
```